# Git Merge Issues from multiple branches

Tags: git, merge

I have a project with multiple subfolders and multiple engineers working on it. It only has a single git repo for the top folder.

All the developers checkout a common master on Monday and create their individual branches from it. They edit code, mostly on separate files and folders, but there are some files that are common and edited by all parties.

My problem comes in that I may merge one developers branch into master and commit and push that. If that developer only worked on files 1 and 2, those are the only one to be updated in the commit. That's great.

A second developer works on files 3 and 4 and when that is merged after the merge of developer 1, I sometimes see strange behavior, it is almost as if the previous merged changes are "un-merged".

On common files, I sometimes get conflicts and use meld to merge them manually.

I cannot quite put my finger on the exact problem yet, but was hoping that the community might point be in the right direction.

Am I going about the merge in the wrong way?

Is there a way to merge every file that shows changes manually with merge tool like meld? I know it will take longer, but I cannot keep wasting the time of my developers with incorrect merges.

Comment: Are you saying your process is that everyone creates a personal branch to work on on Monday, and presumably merge on Friday, regardless of what they were working on or the state of their branch? If so, that's going to cause a lot of problems.

Comment: There are many ways to avoid merge conflicts. However it can't be completely stopped (not in your case). I believe your question should be rephrased to ask which git workflow should I use to avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: @Schwem: The merges are based on completed packages, not strictly on Fridays. The code must always be in working condition.

Comment: @Kumar: I think you are right in that it is probably our chosen workflow that is causing the trouble. Jbu below suggested looking at the workflow in attempt to find one suitable to our flow. I will read through that, hopefully find some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to merge every file that shows changes manually with
>   merge tool like meld?

You can use `git mergetool --tool=meld`

> A second developer works on files 3 and 4 and when that is merged
>   after the merge of developer 1, I sometimes see strange behavior, it
>   is almost as if the previous merged changes are "un-merged".

Sounds like you didn't pull the latest code.  Developer 2 needs to bring in changes of developer 1 to see the previously merged changes.

> I cannot quite put my finger on the exact problem yet, but was hoping
>   that the community might point be in the right direction.
>
> Am I going about the merge in the wrong way?

I think it would benefit you to read up on [git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)(specifically centralized, feature branch, and git workflows).  Identify which model your team is using.

You need to pull your upstream branch which gets the latest commits.  Then you can resolve conflicts after the merge (or actually rebase - info on that found in the link)

Comment: jbu, thanks for the reply, I will go and have a look at the workflows.